# When I choose a date in CalendarView , calendarView.getDate() does not change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, time, android-alertdialog

I have the following code that handles select date in CalendarView.The problem is calendar.getDate ()
still returns the current date, not the date selected in the CalendarView.But the values ​​of year, month and day of month are correct. I have an idea to just set these values ​​on a Calendar, but I don't like this method. Please explain how to make calendarView.getDate () return the result that I selected in
CalendarView

```
    public static AlertDialog getTextDialog(Context ctx) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.calendar_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setView(view);
    CalendarView calendar = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener((view1, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
        Log.e("DATE", Long.toString(view1.getDate()));
        Log.e("DAY", Long.toString(dayOfMonth));
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently selecting and setting is not the same for CalendarView. As you said, just update it manually in the listener so you can access it later with getDate().

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);

        view.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        Log.d("calendar", String.valueOf(view.getDate()));
    }
});
```